# Computer Science: When we say spawn a process, why use spawn?

Tags: meaning

In many docs, such as in http server. We often see "spawn xx processes".

The definition of spawn as a verb is

1.

> (of a fish, frog, mollusk, crustacean, etc.) release or deposit eggs.
>
> "the fish spawn among fine-leaved plants"
>
> (of a fish, frog, etc.) be laid as eggs.

2.

> of a person) produce (offspring).
>
> "why had she married a man who could spawn a boy like that?"
>
> produce or generate, especially in large numbers.
>
> "the decade spawned a bewildering variety of books on the forces"
>
> synonyms: give rise to, bring about, occasion, generate, engender, originate; More
>
> COMPUTING
>
> generate (a dependent or subordinate computer process).

Why not use "spawn" but not "product" or "generate"?

wiki: [Spawn_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(computing))

Comment: Probably because what we *spawn* is a "child process".  It's an extension of the metaphor of the child, using the "produce (offspring)" meaning of "spawn."

Comment: Following on @MarkThompson, spawn works well for this because it indicates that the product / generated thing then lives on its own (executes).

Comment: @MarkThompson I did not think of a need for "probably" or even "the metaphor of" -- it's the verb *spawn* alright.

Comment: Because spawning is quicker and easier than **going into labor**.

Comment: @MarkThompson Yep, in most of time what we spawn is a "child process", so "fork" is more appropriate?

Comment: Well, we use them to mean [different things](http://fixunix.com/unix/84486-difference-between-spawn-fork.html) in programming. When you **fork** a process you get an exact copy (a "clone") of the process you forked. When you **spawn** a process, that new process that has been spawned is not a clone of the parent and generally runs a different executable.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: *Produces* or *generates* would have been fine. Probably used "spawn" because somebody liked the way it *sounded*.

Comment: Atupal, this is as good as it gets for an explanation. Some random person thought it would sound catchy and it does.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the ways that *spawn* is appropriate, catchy, and at the very least sufficient; there is also the factor that Product (produce) and Generate have existing contextual meanings.

A lot of computer programming is deeply tied to mathematics. If we look at math terminology we see that Produce and Generate have clearly defined meanings, and that programming had adopted both of these back in the days of single process computing.
In variable manipulation Produce means to achieve a simple result from a simple foundation ( 4 = 2 + 2 ) and Generate means to achieve a complex result from a simple foundation ( "hash generation", "random number generation", etc.).

So by the time computing was capable of "spawning" child processes those other terms were already reserved.